# correct Image url can't be resolved in JavaFX XML File

Tags: java, xml, javafx, scenebuilder

In my JavaFX GUI I added an image (I set the URL in Scenebuilder)
The XML now looks like this:

```
<ImageView fitHeight="198.66666666666666" fitWidth="149.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
  <image>
    <Image url="@../../../../../../../resources/Bilder/logo-sample.jpg" />
  </image>
</ImageView>
```

When I run the application the Image is simply not showen, although the Path is right. The file wouldn`t be parsed if it would be a wrong path. I can't figure out why the image is not shown in the application, I also tried to go with a path like this

`<img url="@classpath:logo-sample.jpg" />` sadly classpath can't be resolved

Edit:
my fxml is in:

```
src/main/java/at/ac/tuwien/sepm/main/UI
```

the image is in

```
src/main/resources/Bilder/logo-sample.jpg
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just replace the @ from the start of generated path with "file:" and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the runtime classpath is different to your development path - my guess is that you have src/main/java and src/main/resources and so at runtime all is relative to those dirs so if your fxml is in src/main/java/sample and your image in src/main/resources/bilder the runtime path would be @../bilder/bla.png

Comment: my fxml is in src/main/java/at/ac/tuwien/sepm/main/UI
so the runtime path should be `../../../../../../resources/Biler/bla.png` right? Thats what I am using

Comment: ... and where is your bilder - give me the fullpath relative to your project - I'm still sure that "resources" is incorrect because java & resources are the root of the classpath - look at the generated jar (netbeans) or bin-folder (eclipse) to understand see how the runtime classpath looks like